# Can't load boot camp Windows 7 after resizing Mac partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Running Lion with Windows 7 boot camped, I modified my Mac OS X partition and reduced its size by 100 GB. I formatted the new 100Gb to FAT 32.

When I restarted my computer, I received the "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" error. I restarted and logged into Lion and the Startup Disk utility still recognized the boot camp install but I still couldn't restart into Windows. I was still able to see the content of the files in the Boot Camp partition via Finder. I tried running from Windows 7 DVD and repairing, but Windows repair didn't recognize any installs.

In the Disk Utility, I deleted the new partition I created (100gb). After deleting it, I noticed the boot camp partition's name changed to disk0s4 and was marked as FAT 32 format. Now I can't look at the boot camp files in finder and startup disk utility isn't recognizing the boot camp partition.

How can I fix the boot camp boot loader, or ay least access my files from lion?

**Update:** The default boot is going to the Windows partition but it shows the "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" error. I assume that means the partition is still good?

**Update 2:** I ran Windows 7 install via a DVD and got to the point where it shows you a list of drives/partitions available. It showed me the boot camp partition (I recognized it by the partition size, although it was about 15 GB short of what I expected) as being "RAW" format with all space being empty. *sad face*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the files were still fine but some bad things happened to the boot sectors.

I ended up running [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to copy all the files to an external hard drive, but it wasn't able to fix the boot sectors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change any partitions after instaling Windows 7 Bootcamp, otherwise Windows 7 won't work.

Comment: So in other words, if the partition sizes you choose initially are not optimal, you need to redo the entire boot camp install?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem too, and found this thread in search for an answer.

Now I finally I know why - my internal dvd but it is not longer working and I use the external or usb bootable windows 7.

I didn't use the internal dvd for some time and missed the fact that this won't work with out original iMac's dvd being operational.

I recommend you test and get your DVD hardware fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 doesn't run on a FAT Partition.  Now you need to forget your data and reinstall Windows 7 with bootcamp.